# ExecuteGet do not return the updated value from couchbase server

Tags: memcached, couchbase, nosql

We use couchbase server 2.2.0 in our production application.

In the last couple of month , when we ExecuteGet on a value, we get the previous value instead of the updated one.

Example scenario (all the actions are synchronized):
UserBalance_12345 is 500.

```
1. ExecuteSet("UserBalance_12345",1000)
2. ExecuteGet("UserBalance_12345"); -> The result is 500 instead of 1000.
```

This scenario occur very rarely but still happen and make damage to us because people say their balance is not updated immidietly.

How can such a scenario happen in couchbase?
Do you have a solution for this scenario?

Comment: That’s really interresting. The error could happen in many other NoSQL DB’s but as I got the structure of CouchBase explained shouldn’t happen there. Since couchbase should first update the cached ...

Answer (score 0):

A long time ago, I've also expirienced this issue. Sometimes it returned incorrect values. There are also some [forum topics](http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/expected-behaviour-executeget) about this. But in my case that data wasn't so important and that issue raised very rarely, so I actually don't tried to figure out what causes it. And this issue is related .net sdk, because i.e. in nodejs sdk with js callbacks it never happend to me.

But I have sevral ideas that may help you.

1) Try to add to your ExecuteStore `persist` parameter:

```
PersistTo persistTo = PersistTo.One;
var result = _Client.ExecuteStore(StoreMode.Set, key, value, persistTo);
```

2) If you store user balance in separate key (just like in question) and it's type fits to ulong you can try to use [`Increment` or `ExecuteDecrement`](http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-sdk-net-1.3/#increment-methods) function instead of ExecuteStore. Increment/decrement functions are usally work better than store and they are atomic.

Comment: It is a nice idea but the main problem is that balance is only one example, it happens in a lot more keys.
What i am trying to figure out is if there is a bug in couchbase server or .net sdk that can cause such a thing.

Comment: I can say that I never experienced this bug with nodejs sdk (which is build on top of libcouchbase). If you have web application try to separate updating and getting new value in two separate requests (i.e 2 ajax queries: first updates balance, second waits for some milliseconds and gets updated information from server). That trick helped me with [couchbase's views updates](http://www.couchbase.com/communities/q-and-a/couchbase-update-view-after-add-doc). May be this issue is related to .net sdk's connection pooling, but I don't sure.

Comment: Yeah that is actually what we tried and it probably solved the problem.
But, we are looking for a cleaner way to solve it (if there is one).
And if there is a bug we want to be aware to this bug to handle it approprietly.